# Display Latest Post on a Page Conditionally

Tags: conditional-tags

So I'm wondering exactly how I could display my latest post on a page only in certain conditions. I've been looking over the conditions page in the codex, but I'm not seeing how I could do what I have in mind.    For example: I will have multiple vendors selling on my site. Each vendor will have their own page on the site. There will be one featured item for sale on the home page,(which we figured out how to do here: [Display newest post's custom field content on homepage, daily](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/62464/display-newest-posts-custom-field-content-on-homepage-daily/62478#62478) ) and when it happens to be a certain vendor's item, I would like the post to display on their specific page as well. So I would need to only show the newest post(again, I got help with this in the provided link) on their page, ONLY when it happens to be their item.   As always, thanks in advance!

Comment: so are you asking to display the vendor's information on the home page, or are you asking to highlight the featured item on the vendor's page?

Comment: Also, what's the relationship between a Product and a Vendor? how have you set them up? How do you decide when a vendor should be the featured one - is it always the same vendor forever, or does that change often? Do you have a way to change the featured vendor on the back-end, or do you just plan on changing it in the code every once and a while?

Comment: I'm trying to highlight the featured item on the vendor's page, if it happens to be their item. It will be changed often, maybe even daily if it takes off well enough. Basically, if the vendor agrees to offer a product for a discount, their item will be featured on the home page. When that happens, I would like for that same post to be shown on their individual page. It will be changed in the backend, via custom fields if all goes as planned.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly you could wrap the code on the vendor's page in a comparison. So if the vendor's name is the Title of their page, and the newest post has a meta field that hold's the vendor's name, it could look like this:

```
$my_most_recent_post = get_posts( 'numberposts=1' );
$my_most_recent_post_id = $my_most_recent_post[0]->ID;
// Get the featured item's meta information here
$meta = get_post_meta($my_most_recent_post_id, 'my_custom_meta', $single = true);

if ( $meta == 'Featured Vendor' )
{
    // display the featured vendor information here
}
```

I'm assuming that you're storing vendor information with all your product entries. Whether you store the title of the vendor, the unique ID, or the slug, that comparison should be similar.

Comment: Very cool! Thank you for your reply! I will give this a go.

Comment: Do you think you'd have a few minutes to help me with this further? I have been trying to get this and other variations of this to work all morning, but I'm not having any luck at all. nothing is being output whatsoever.

Comment: So basically, I'm on the vendor's page, and what your code is saying is that if the Title of the vendors page matches a custom field on the newest post, then I should be able to display the newest post on the vendors page. For example, let's say the vendor's name and page is Awesome Vendor, then all I would need to do is add a custom field to the newest post that holds, "Awesome Vendor" in it right? It's just not working. Do I need start the loop? Because I'm trying that now, and that's not working either.

Comment: edited for a bit more clarity.

Comment: Ok awesome! Thank you for replying again. I will give this a try ASAP, and report back.

Comment: I just can't seem to get this to work, haha! It seems like it should work!  Here is what I'm doing in a pastebin:  http://pastebin.com/9B7G1VaE  That code is on my vendor page template, which I would like it to show the Featured Item for sale if it happens to be their product, as we discussed above.  The newest item(post) has a meta box with "Awesome Food Cart" inserted in it, so our code is saying that if that is the case, it should be outputting the meta of "deal-title" onto our vendor's page, right? Or am I missing something? Thanks!

Comment: Do you have errors turned on? Are you getting any errors?

Comment: No. no errors at all. Nothing shows. Just blank. Very odd!

Comment: You can turn on errors in your wp-config.php file. Look for the line that says `define('WP_DEBUG', false);` and switch it to `true`. Just make sure to switch it back before you go live! A blank page usually means there are PHP errors, but you can't see them because error reporting is turned off.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry I think I said that wrong. The page itself is showing. In other words, all other content is showing, just not the bit of code we are working with. I meant What I'm trying to get to show with our code, is blank.

Comment: Try this: http://pastebin.com/DTxKwZEh. It looks like you're trying to access an array on line 6, where it's a string.

Comment: Heh, and that was my mistake originally. Editing the answer to match.

Comment: Well Crap! Still not working. So, I'm displaying our code on my custom template page that will be powering all vendor's pages. In my newest post, I have two meta boxes. One titled "vendor name", and another one named "deal title". Within the vendor name box, I have "Awesome Food Cart" in it, and within the deal title meta box I have "Buy One Entree, Get One Free" in it. So, that is what I should be seeing right? What's in the "deal-title" box should be showing. I hate to keep bugging you. If you don't have time, I understand.

Comment: Just a quick bit of debugging: before the "if" statement above, add a line `echo $meta;` and after the closing curly quote in the `if ($meta == 'Awesome Food Cart' { echo $deal_title_stuff }` add `else { echo "It's not Awesome Food Cart'; }`. This can help us narrow down where the problem is depending on what you end up seeing.

Comment: We are getting somewhere!! Ok, so by adding in the new "echo $meta;" before it all, it outputs the "vendor-name" instead of the "deal-title". Also, it does output the else statement of "It's not Awesome Food Cart".  So I need to work on this, so that it does output the Deal Title. Ultimately, I would love to make it not only output the newest post's title, but the featured image, and make the title a link, so that users can go right to it. That is something I will experiment with.

Comment: Shouldn't it be returning the vendor name in the first bit? Isn't that the correct behavior? But the 'vendor-name' does not equal the on you want to feature? Maybe I'm losing it!

Comment: Ohhh, see that is where I am misunderstanding it. I thought it was just saying to look for the meta box titled "vendor name". Then if "Awesome Food Cart" is within that box, then echo "deal-title"  You aren't losing it, I just really HAVE to learn php!

Comment: .... i think that _is_ what it was saying. Look for a piece of meta information of ID 'vendor-name.' If the vendor name is equal to 'Awesome Food Cart' then echo the title of the deal. I think you had it right.

Comment: Thank you. Ok, so I just have to figure out why it's not echoing the title of the deal then.

Comment: By adding in the extra "echo ?meta;" in there, we are  disregarding this part of the code:   "if ( $meta['vendor-name'] == 'Awesome Food Cart' )
{
    echo get_post_meta( $my_most_recent_post_id, 'deal-title', true ); "  So I have to figure out to get the "if" statement to work still.

Comment: Well, that's why we're doing the first `echo $meta;` If that echo statement is what you expect (it's "Awesome Food Cart" _exactly_) than the If statement should be true and the code between the `{}` will be executed.